# How consume serve data in *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Here i create a Simple service for accessing http service please helpme how can i bind this service information in *ngFor

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
     import {Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    @Injectable()
    export class EmployeeService {
        constructor(private http: Http) { }
    GetStudentData() {

        this.http.get('api/Employee').subscribe(response => {

            this.student = response.json();
                })
    }
    }
```

Student.component.ts

```
 GetStudentData() {
        var studentser = this.EmpServ.GetStudentData();
                     //Here How can i Bind

    }
```

Her how can i save data in one varialble and used in

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html

Comment: what do you mean by create a Simple constructor for accessing http service?

Comment: yes here im accessing this http like    this.http.get('api/Employee').subscribe(response => {

           this.student = response.json();
             })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the data from the service and bind inside the component,

```
GetStudentData() {
       this.http.get('api/Employee').subscribe(response => {
       this.student = response.json();
       })
  return this.student;
}
```